# Docker authentication with GCP from R

Tags: r, docker, google-cloud-platform, vetiver

I've built a docker image from R via the terminal `(docker build -t penguins .)`

When I try to run the image via the terminal `(docker run --rm -e .Renviron -p 8000:8000 penguins)`

I've passed in my .Renviron file which contains my environmental variables (`GCE_AUTH_FILE`) which points to my service account json file.

When I run the docker image I receive the following error pointing to a missing .httr_auth file however when I run `httr::with_verbose(googleAuthR::gar_auth_service(json_file = Sys.getenv("GCE_AUTH_FILE")))` I get a http 200 which is good news

I'm confused what needs to be done to get authenticated from within the docker image.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: You may already have read this, but when I need to set up GCP to use with Docker, I [use the advice in this vignette](https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html). It sounds like you may be trying to use your service account JSON from within your Docker container, even though it exists outside the container.